# Most reliable way to automatically choose line styles in matplotlib in combination with seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm looking for a reliable way to automatically choose line styles for my plots. Right now I have 8 lines for a plot and I hope it is feasible to automatically choose line styles that are distinguishable from each other.

As of now, I have basically two ways. Setting markers or defining styles. Both seem to have some problems with seaborn. The first is to use a cycler:

```
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':', '-.']))
```

If I use that, either it overrides seaborn settings, or it gets overwritten by seaborn, depending which one I set first. 
The other way I found in one of the examples and sets the markers for the lines:

```
def makeStyles():
    markers = []
    for m in Line2D.markers:
        try:
            if len(m) == 1 and m != ' ':
                markers.append(m)
        except TypeError:
            pass

    styles = markers + [
        r'$\lambda$',
        r'$\bowtie$',
        r'$\circlearrowleft$',
        r'$\clubsuit$',
        r'$\checkmark$']
    return styles
```

The problem here is, that quite some of the markers seem to be the same, which is just a line without a marker.

Is there any other way that works reliable and works with seaborn?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the rcParams that you have in matplotlib and are using the latest version of seaborn (>= 0.7.1), the easiest way is to use `import seaborn.apionly` as explained in [what's new](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/whatsnew.html)